# StreamBuilder snapshot is inactive on creating own stream

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

It is a firebase authentication system with email verification. I am using 2 streams, one is firebase authstatechanges and one of my own to check mail verification status.

I am using a stream combiner for combining 2 streams.

On combining 2 streams and calling the function in stream builder, the snapshot was returning an inactive state. It was not even entering the method "combinestream". Then I tried checking my own stream and passed it to streambuilder alone this time. I found out that it was giving the same problem.

Here is my stream controller code with 2 streams combined:

```
class AuthService {

  final userVerificationStreamController = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();

  final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  MyUser? _userFromFirebase(auth.User? newUser) {
    if (newUser == null) {
      return null;
    }
    print("^^^^^------?>>>>>>>>>    ${newUser.uid} ,, ${newUser.email} ,, ${newUser.emailVerified}");
    return MyUser(newUser.uid, newUser.email,newUser.emailVerified);
  }

  Stream<CombineStreamer> get combineStream {
    Stream<MyUser?> firebaseAuthStream = _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
    Stream<bool> userVerificationStream = userVerificationStreamController.stream;
    print("######___>>>>>>>>>>   COMBINING STREAMS");
    return firebaseAuthStream.combineLatest(userVerificationStream, (p0, p1){
      if(p0==null){
        userVerificationStreamController.sink.add(false);
      }
      else if(p0.isEmailVerified){
        userVerificationStreamController.sink.add(true);
      }

      if (p1.toString().toLowerCase() == 'true') {
        print("______+++++++___******  ${p1.toString().toLowerCase()}");
        return CombineStreamer(p0,true);
      } else{

        print("______+++++++___>>>>>>  ${p1.toString().toLowerCase()}");
        return CombineStreamer(p0,false);
      }
  }

.....
....
}
```

I called this combineStream method in wrapper class like:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: authService.combineStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active){
          print("!!!!___--->>>>>   THE STATE IS ACTIVE");
          CombineStreamer? streamedData = snapshot.data;
          if(streamedData!=null) {
            if(streamedData.user == null || !streamedData.isUserVerified){
              print("!!!!___--->>>>>   GOING TO LOGIN PAGE");
              return LoginPage();
            }
            else{
              print("!!!!___--->>>>>   GOING TO HOMEPAGE");
              return HomePage();
            }
          }
          else{
            print("!!!!!!######  SNAPSHOT IS NULL");
            return const Scaffold(body: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.red,),);
          }
        }
        else{
          print("!!!!___--->>>>>   SHOWING CIRCULAR INDICATOR");
          return const Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),));
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Here it ALWAYS shows me the circular progress indicator of blue color the default one, where the snapshot is inactive. I am not able to figure out what's causing this problem. Please look into this.
And add the comment if you think something is missing. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really want to do something based on the connection state being active? According to the docs for that state, I suspect that is not what you want in your case: 

"Connected to an active asynchronous computation.
For example, a Stream that has returned at least one value, but is not yet done."

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState.html

Comment: I think it should work like this, as for only authstatechanges stream it is working perfectly!! Also there active helps in determining if stream is still open or not and most of the open source code bases use it1

Comment: so, please look into it. Thanks!!